# How to start the tomcat webapp for mondrian pentaho

Tags: java, tomcat, ubuntu, pentaho, mondrian

I am following this [tutorial](http://akbarahmed.com/2012/07/19/install-mondrian-3-4-1/) and i am new to java and tomcat

The article say to go to:

```
cd /opt/pentaho/biserver-ce/tomcat/bin`
```

but i don't have tomcat folder in there.

Also the user say that:

> I have changed the default Pentaho BI Server port from 8080 to 8585

how can i change that port and in which file.

Do i need to install BI server as well to go to the url ( `http://localhost:8585/mondrian` )?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you unzip the pentaho bi sever file after installing it you will find tomcat folder under bi-server folder, if you are not able to find it then their is problem in downloading file, so download it again..

for changing default port number, you can change it

\biserver-ce\tomcat\webapps\pentaho\WEB-INF

under this you will find web.xml file

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>base-url</param-name>
    <param-value>http://192.168.60.195:8080/pentaho/</param-value>
</context-param>
```

here instead of 8080 change the port number which suits you.